# SFML Font: failed to load font

Tags: visual-c++, fonts, visual-studio-2015, sfml

I'm using VS 2015 with the latest sfml. All the configuration works. I'm using debug libs (...-d.lib), etc.

I'm calling font.loadfromfile() in my main function. I placed the font file into my project folder. I checked over and over again that the default directory for VS is my project folder. I even manually changed it to "C:\sfmlprojects\sfmlpong\sfmlpong\" just to be sure. Although the font file is in that folder, I'm still getting the error "failed to load font ... ".

I've looked at dozens of posts and every single one of them either says to double check font file is in the right location, or a mixing debug/release lib issue, either of which seems to be my problem.

I am using VS 2015 on a virtual machine on my Mac. Could this be messing up the program directory? This is the only reason I can think of that would make me place the font file in the wrong directory.

Any insight as to why font is failing to load even though its in the right directory/with the right libs would be immensely helpful.

Comment: You'll need to include the filename at the end like `C:\sfmlprojects\sfmlpong\sfmlpong\[filename]`. If that doesn't work perhaps the problem is caused by the font file itself... Does the font format match one of the ones listed in the documentation for `font::loadfromfile`? Have you tried loading a different font?

Comment: I forgot to post the filename at the end, but that is indeed what I did. It is a TrueType font so it should be acceptable. I just skipped it and implemented other stuff in my program. I'll go back to it and check if it's the font file that is faulty.

Comment: You could also examine the content of `std::err` - it looks like the font loading functions report the specific error on that stream by default.